# Is there a way use the results from a run function to create a new DataFrame from the vaderSentiment package

Tags: python

Below is the code in question. I am trying to take the results (last line) and break it up into a DataFrame so that it will look like this:

```
This phone is super cool. | neg | 0.0 | neu | 0.326 | pos | 0.674 | compound | 0.7351
```

---

!pip install vaderSentiment  << Run to install vaderSentiment package

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()



def sentiment_analyzer_scores (sentence):

    score = analyzer.polarity_scores(sentence)

    print("{:-<40} {}".format(sentence, str(score)))

sentiment_analyzer_scores("This phone is super cool.")
```

---

Result >>

```
This phone is super cool.--------------- {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.326, 'pos': 0.674, 'compound': 0.7351}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. See below:

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

def sas_neg (sentence):
    score = analyzer.polarity_scores(sentence)
    x = score['neg']*100
    return x
def sas_neu (sentence):
    score = analyzer.polarity_scores(sentence)
    y = score['neu']*100 
    return y
def sas_pos (sentence):
    score = analyzer.polarity_scores(sentence)
    z = score['pos']*100
    return z
Comments = xlsx_read['Customer Comments']
r_neg = xlsx_read.apply(lambda x: sas_neg(x['Customer Comments']),axis =1)
r_neu = xlsx_read.apply(lambda x: sas_neu(x['Customer Comments']),axis =1)
r_pos = xlsx_read.apply(lambda x: sas_pos(x['Customer Comments']),axis =1)
Sentiment = Comments, r_neg, r_neu, r_pos; 
Sentiment = pd.DataFrame(Sentiment);
Sentiment = Sentiment.T;
Sentiment = Sentiment.set_axis(['Customer Comments','Negative', 'Neutral', 'Postive'], axis=1, inplace=False);
Sentiment
```